# Apache named-based VirtualHost configuration for multiple sites in one host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, url-rewriting

My problem is simple and i think the solution also.
I search the forums about 2-3 hours and didnt my answer... -_-' .

I got "space" in a host provider. So they gave me a "www" directory.
I have multiple folders in this directory so it's like:

www--
     |
     /Folder1
     /Folder2
     /Folder3 etc.etc.....
Each folder represents a website.
So i want to redirect each website to each folder e.g. :

`www.example1.com -> Folder1`
`www.example2.com -> Folder2`
`www.example3.com -> Folder3 etc....`

-BUT- without showing the subfolder of each ...
So this is NOT a solution: www.example1.com/Folder1 
This IS a solution: www.example1.com .
How can i modify my .htaccess file in root WWW ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: would you be so kind as to accept the first, correctly posted answer below?

Answer (score 1):

This has to be done through your http server configuration (like apache).

VirtualHosts is how you split multiple domains across one computer, and their respective .htaccess configuration will give you protection for your site (username/password).

If you just want to split the computer into multiple hosts, you don't need to use .htaccess.

See the following links
[Here are some VirtualHost Configuration Examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html)
[Apache HTTP Server Tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html)
[Server Config Files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html)

Excerpt from the "example's" link on "**Name-Based Virtual Hosts**":

```
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.50>
    DocumentRoot /www/example1
    ServerName www.example.com

    # Other directives here ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.50>
    DocumentRoot /www/example2
    ServerName www.example.org

    # Other directives here ...
</VirtualHost>
```

The configuration file is usually located in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` which then reads from `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf` which are essentially symbolic links to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf`  - those files are used with the above code to accomplish the results you describe.

You may also be interested looking into [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main), an alternative to apache2.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess is not what you're looking for. Instead, read up on **Name-based Virtual Host Support**. You will need to add some entries to your **httpd.conf** file to point each domain to the correct folder in the www directory. It should be pretty straight forward.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html